# Effect of PyGTK clipboard set_text persists only while process is running

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, clipboard

I have the following script `clip-test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk

gtk.Clipboard().set_text("exciting clipboard contents")
gtk.Clipboard().set_can_store(None) # not sure if these last two lines are useful
gtk.Clipboard().store()
```

When I run this like so:

```
python clip-test.py
```

it doesn't work. The clipboard is unchanged. We can elucidate the issue by running it in interactive mode and not letting the process finish:

```
python -i clip-test.py
```

Before leaving interactive mode, try pasting somewhere. The clipboard is changed; it works. After closing python, the clipboard returns to what it was before.

One thought was that this has something to do with which `display` and `selection` clipboard the code is accessing by default, but I've tried varying those parameters and I still can't get it to work.

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and python-gtk2 2.24.0-3build1, running Kubuntu 13.04.

What gives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a GTK or PyGTK issue, but a consequence of how X11 copying and pasting works. When you press <kbd>^C</kbd> in an X11 application, you haven't really copied anything yet, you have just instructed the application to remember the data for possible later use. *Only when a "paste" is initiated* does the data get transmitted to the paster. This saves resources and enables the copier and the paster to negotiate a data transfer format that best suits them. This is explained in some detail in [the classic text by Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).

Modern desktop environments [do attempt to hold on](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/ClipboardManager) to the clipboard contents, but you must enter the main loop and remain in it for long enough for the clipboard manager to grab your clipboard contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk, gobject

gtk.Clipboard().set_text("exciting clipboard contents")
gobject.timeout_add(100, gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```

The `set_can_store()` and `store()` should be able to speed up the process, some googling showed that [programs are using them](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2011/08/coding-copy-and-paste-functionality.html) to save the clipboard data in a destroy handler. It's not clear why it doesn't work for you — perhaps you should be calling `set_can_store([("UTF8_STRING", 0, 0)])` instead of `set_can_store(None)`.

Comment: Slightly strange but makes tons of sense, thanks for the thorough explanation and links.