# How to share clipboard data beetween processes in GTK?

Tags: python, pygtk

I want to:

1. put some text into clipboard
2. end my program
3. paste data into other application

but my code is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gtk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'put':
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        clipboard.set_text('It\'s working')
        clipboard.store()
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'get':
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        text = clipboard.wait_for_text()
        print('Text from clipboard: ', text)
```

I put text into clipboard by executing `python2 ./test.py put` and after that i want to get ext from clipboard with `python2 ./test.py get`.

Why clipboard.wait_for_text() always return None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to enter main loop to let the clipboard manager get the text ([Effect of PyGTK clipboard set_text persists only while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241203/effect-of-pygtk-clipboard-set-text-persists-only-while-process-is-running))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gtk, gobject


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == 'put':
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        clipboard.set_text('It\'s working')
        clipboard.store()
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'get':
        clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
        text = clipboard.wait_for_text()
        if text == None:
            print("empty text")
        else:
            print('Text from clipboard: ', text)
gobject.timeout_add(100, gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

For GTK3:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class CopyToClipboard(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(CopyToClipboard, self).__init__()
        clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
        clipboard.set_text(text, -1)
        clipboard.store()

CopyToClipboard("your text goes here\n")
```